# html links not working on iphone

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having some trouble with my website. Some of links are not working when I test the site with my iPhone but they work correctly on my desktop computer. I'm trying to figure out if this is a css/js issue. I haven't run into this issue before so I'm having some trouble trying to figure out how to debug it.

```
<div class="row">
  <div id="primary" class="content-area main-content-inner col-sm-12 col-md-8 pull-left">...</div>
  <div id="secondary" class="widget-area col-sm-12 col-md-4" role="complementary">...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You'll need to post your actual code if you want help debugging; what version of BS? Are you using vanilla CSS? are you using vendor prefixes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `pull-left` from your `#primary` div

Since you're using col-* classes, they'll take care of floating positions, what happens in your case is  that when you're in a small device, both divs  (primary and secondary) take 12 columns, but one of them is floated left because of pull-left, so that div overlaps on the other one, that's why you couldn't click your link.